# Creating a unique list from two tables read from filecontents

Tags: pgfplotstable, loops, filecontents

I have two tables.. one contains attributes with values e.g.

```
Name percentage
Atr1 80
Atr2 20
Atr3 50
```

and the other one contains tools for that attribute

```
Attribute Tool
Atr1       SK
Atr1       SL
Atr2.      UP
Atr3       SK
```

I need to have a list of tools from the top two attributes in table 1, but the list has to be unique in case that there is the same tool for each attribute.

Tools from top two attributes in first table (Atr1 and Atr3) are

```
SK
SL
SK
```

I need to remove extra SK so that the list would look like this

```
SK
SL
```

Here is what I got so far..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}



\begin{filecontents*}{tools.dat}
Name Abbreviation 
Tool1 SL 
Tool2 SK 
Tool3  UP
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{tabletools.dat}
Attribute Tool
SV CA
SV MC
BK PT
BK PR
MI SP
MI MC
Inter SL
Inter SK
Intra MC
Intra MS
VL AA
VL MC
LM LC
LM ME
N SS
N MC
R MC
R GB
I LC
I CA
A UP
A SL
S SK
S AP
E SM
E MC
C MC
C CA
\end{filecontents*}


 \begin{filecontents*}{topstyles.dat} 
    Name Abbreviation percentage 
    Inter Inter 0
    Music MI 0
    S-Visual SV 0
    V-Linguistic VL 5
    B-Kinesthetic BK 0 
    Intraper Intra 0
    Logic-Math LM 20
    Natural N 10
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


 \pgfplotstableread[columns={Name,Abbreviation,percentage}]{topstyles.dat}\datatableA
 \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={percentage}, sort cmp=int >]{\datatablesorted}{\datatableA}
 \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatablesorted} 
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{Abbreviation}\of{\datatablesorted}
\edef\topworkabbr{\pgfplotsretval}

\pgfplotstableread[columns={Attribute,Tool}]{tabletools.dat}\datatableB
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatableB} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\RowsInTable}{\pgfplotsretval-1} 
 \foreach \k in {0,...,\RowsInTable}{
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Attribute}\of{\datatableB}
\edef\itest{\ifstrequal{\pgfplotsretval}{\topworkabbr}{1}{0}}
\itest
\ifnum\itest=1
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Tool}\of{\datatableB}
\pgfplotsretval
\fi
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is the issue solved? How?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the question but this replaces the nonworking equality test by a working one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% \usepackage{ifthen}
% \usepackage{etoolbox}



\begin{filecontents*}{tools.dat}
Name Abbreviation 
Tool1 SL 
Tool2 SK 
Tool3  UP
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{tabletools.dat}
Attribute Tool
SV CA
SV MC
BK PT
BK PR
MI SP
MI MC
Inter SL
Inter SK
Intra MC
Intra MS
VL AA
VL MC
LM LC
LM ME
N SS
N MC
R MC
R GB
I LC
I CA
A UP
A SL
S SK
S AP
E SM
E MC
C MC
C CA
\end{filecontents*}


 \begin{filecontents*}{topstyles.dat} 
    Name Abbreviation percentage 
    Inter Inter 0
    Music MI 0
    S-Visual SV 0
    V-Linguistic VL 5
    B-Kinesthetic BK 0 
    Intraper Intra 0
    Logic-Math LM 20
    Natural N 10
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


 \pgfplotstableread[columns={Name,Abbreviation,percentage}]{topstyles.dat}\datatableA
 \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={percentage}, sort cmp=int >]{\datatablesorted}{\datatableA}
 \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatablesorted} 
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{Abbreviation}\of{\datatablesorted}
\edef\topworkabbr{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstableread[columns={Attribute,Tool}]{tabletools.dat}\datatableB
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatableB} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\RowsInTable}{\pgfplotsretval-1} 
 \foreach \k in {0,...,\RowsInTable}{
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Attribute}\of{\datatableB}
 \edef\eltest{\pgfplotsretval}
 \ifx\eltest\topworkabbr\relax%
  \typeout{\eltest=\topworkabbr}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Tool}\of{\datatableB}
  \pgfplotsretval
 \fi
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps with the condition.. but I still need to have result placed in a list, where I can remove the duplicates..

Comment: @Almic7 It is no problem to create a list but I simply do not understand " but I still need to have result placed in a list, where I can remove the duplicates." Please provide a concise description of the desired outcome.

Comment: You have managed to fix my code so I get strings like SK, SL etc.. these strings I need to place dynamically in a list. Before being added to the list, I need to check if a new string is already added.. so e.g. I have added two strings SKSL and I want to add again SL, it would not be possible because SL already is added.. I've been using \IfSubStr and appending strings in a list with these commands \def\mystring{} 
\def\extendmystring#1#2{\edef\mystring{#1\mystring#2}}, but somehow \mystring is rewritten with each loop iteration..

Comment: @Almic7 I am sorry, I am still in the dark. In your code you go for the very first entry. From your description it seems more that you want to weed out *all* duplicates. Is that what you want?